# SQL Query with variable injection - SQL Alchemy - Python

Tags: python, sql, variables, sqlalchemy, user-input

i have a question regarding variable injection into sql query with sqlalchemy/python(3.8).

What i researched so far was adding %s and also email_address=? and then adding it (email_address) but without success

What i am trying to do is capture user input and run a select query dynamically.

```html
print(" What is the email address??")
email_address = input()
conn = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://test_table:username@127.0.0.1:3306/test_db?driver=SQL Server?Trusted_Connection=yes'", echo = False)
sql = pd.read_sql('Select id,email_address from test_table where email_address = email_address', conn)
print(sql)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
print(" What is the email address??")
email_address = input()
conn = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://test_table:username@127.0.0.1:3306/test_db?driver=SQL Server?Trusted_Connection=yes'", echo = False)
sql = pd.read_sql('Select id,email_address from test_table where email_addres=?', conn, params=(email_addres,))
print(sql)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Rafael  i just tried it and the following displayed:xception has occurred: ProgrammingError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: <module>)
(pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
[SQL: Select id,email_address from test table where email_address = %(email_address)s]
[parameters: {'email_address': 'daniel'}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405) -- which is quite weird as the db doesnt drop,the table exists,the info in the table exists

Comment: you are using pyodbc. so my answer was wrong. change  `email_address = %(email_address)s` to `email_addres=?`, and `params={"email_address": email_addres}` to `params=(email_addres,)`. I will update the answer if this solve your problem

Comment: well, this worked like *magic*, thank you very much for the answer. Will this work with multiple variables? email_address =?  and id=?', conn, params=(email_address,id,)) -- ? -- LE, works, thanks!